# How to handle ampersands in URL parameters?

Tags: asp-classic, urlencode

I am having the following issue:

I am using an application that allows users to concatenate text to build a URL that passes parameters to an ASP page via GET method, i.e. something like:

```
http://myhostname/process.asp?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Problem is value1 and value2 can contain the ampersand symbol, which is not interpreted as a text character.

The most popular solution to this issue is to encode the URL, which is not an option for me because I cannot modify the program that builds the URL. I can modify the process.asp page, but not the program that concatenates the text fields and builds the URL.

Things I've tried to search for are:

- How to encode a URL using javascript directly in the browser
- How to change IIS default behaviour when reading an &
- Alternative ways to pass parameters, i.e. something like passing them as a single string of characters separated with pipes

Hope you can give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the entire query string and parse it yourself, like this:

```
  q = Request.QueryString
  a = Split(q, "=")
  i = 1
  For Each s In a
    If i mod 2 = 0 Then
      If InStr(s, "&") <> InStrRev(s, "&") Then
        Response.Write "Value: " & Left(s, InStrRev(s, "&") - 1) & "<br/>"
        hidingParam = Right(s, Len(s) - InStrRev(s, "&"))
        Response.Write "PAramName: " & hidingParam & "<br/>"
        i = i + 1
      Else
        Response.Write "Value: " & s & "<br/>"
      End If
    Else
      Response.Write "PAramName: " & s & "<br/>"
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next
```

**Result:**

URL: `...?Q=abc&def&P=123` produces

> PAramName: Q 
> Value: abc&def 
> PAramName: P 
> Value: 123

Note that this is less than robust. I am only illustrating my idea. I didn't test with no `&`.

It also doens't handle multiple "=" characters (if that's a possiblity as well).

Answer (score -1):

If there are 2 (or more) ampersands in-between the equals, then only the last one is a parameter separator. So, using your URL above, and assuming that *value1* = "**abc&def**", and *value2* = "**123**", then the URL will look like:

```
http://myhostname/process.asp?param1=abc&def&param2=123
```

Notice there's 2 ampersands in-between the 2 equals. The last one will be your parameter separator, the rest are part of the value. And any ampersands after the last equals are also part of the value.

You'll have to dissect the incoming URL and apply the appropriate logic.

Comment: I am unable to confirm what you're saying on my dev. machine. `Request.QueryString("param1")` returns `abc`, not `abc&def`.

Comment: You can't do Request.QueryString. You have to read the entire URL and parse it yourself.